# Gdb layout asm window showing raw instruction opcodes and operands

Tags: linux, gdb, executable, elf, instructions

When I use `layout asm` command I see the following:

```
│0x4000f2 <_start+18>    mov    $0xffff0000,%eax
```

When I use `disas /r` command I see the following:

```
0x00000000004000f2 <+18>:    b8 00 00 ff ff  mov    $0xffff0000,%eax
```

That is, in the latter case, I can also see the opcode `b8` and the operand.

How should I adjust the command `layout asm` or what command should I run additionally to see the raw instructions in the `asm` window too? Thank you.